# Maximum decimal places in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

We have an oracle database with a NUMBER field with 40 decimal places.  From my research, there is a maximum of 30 decimal places in SQL Server.

I would like to avoid truncating.  How would we move this kind of data over?

Comment: IIRC Oracle supports only up to 38 decimal places which is the same as numeric is sql server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx Oracle documentation supports my memory https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832

Comment: Wrong: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-nov/o61plsql-512011.html

Comment: Well I guess it changes depending on which documentation you look at. Since sql server only allows up to 38 decimal places you are going to have to get creative if you really can't loose any precision. My curiosity has the best of me here. What are you working with that requires that much precision?